# IndexOf method not working as expected JAVASCRIPT

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, sorting, indexof

```
nodesData=[
    {name:'name1'},
    {name:'name2'},
    {name:'name1'},
    {name:'name3'},
]

uniqData=[
    {name:'name1'}
    {name:'name2'}
    {name:'name3'}
]

for (let i = 0; i < nodesData.length; i += 2) {
  const currentSource = nodesData[i];
  const currentTarget = nodesData[i + 1];

  const currentData = {
    source: uniqData.indexOf(currentSource),
    target: uniqData.indexOf(currentTarget),
  };
}
```

So I've got two lists with objects. First list is list with objects that contains names, and other list is list generated with function that I've made for removing duplicates.The problem is when I use for loop and loop through nodesData list only the first time I get only for source index of -1...why? and other indexOf work expected.

So the console.log would be:

```
source:-1, target:1

source:0, target:2
```

Comment: First, you are missing `,` in `uniqData`. Second, your code log `source: -1, target: -1` twice

Comment: You should get all `-1` for `currentData` in all iteration. You want to generate `uniqData`. So, `uniqData` is empty. and `indexOf` `uniqData` will always give you `-1`

Comment: You're comparing objects with a different reference. So the `indexOf` will always return `-1` because for us the values seem similar but actually they aren't

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The objects in the array have differents references even if they looks like they are the same. Basically :

```js
console.log({name: 'name1'} === {name: 'name1'}); // false
```

It prints `false` because the compared objects haven't the same references even if they are similar.

So in your example the [indexOf](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) method returns -1 because the objects have not the same reference (again even if they looks like they are equal).

Since you can't directly use `indexOf` you have to first get the object's reference with [find](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) and then you can use `indexOf`, like this :

```js
const nodesData=[
    {name:'name1'},
    {name:'name2'},
    {name:'name1'},
    {name:'name3'},
]

const uniqData=[
    {name:'name1'},
    {name:'name2'},
    {name:'name3'},
]

for (let i = 0; i < nodesData.length; i += 2) {
  const currentSource = nodesData[i];
  const currentTarget = nodesData[i + 1];

  const currentData = {
    source: uniqData.indexOf(uniqData.find(({name}) => name === currentSource.name)),
    target: uniqData.indexOf(uniqData.find(({name}) => name === currentTarget.name)),
  };
  
  console.log(currentData);
}
```

**Note :**

I used [destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) in order to directly get the `name` property